# CREATE VIEW in PostGIS from node.js results in a table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgis, sql-view, knex.js

I am trying to create a spatial view in PosGIS 2.1.2 from node.js. I tried with knex (0.7.6) and with pg (4.3.0), but every time I run the query a table is created in the database instead of a view.

This is the SQL statement I use:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT DISTINCT a.*
  FROM layer_1 AS a, layer_2 AS b
  WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 10);
```

What am I doing wrong?

The reason I want to create a view is to keep `my_view` updated whenever `layer_1` or `layer_2` is modified.

**EDIT**

**Please discard this question!** I found that the issue is not as I describe above. The issue in fact was that I first used a `CREATE TABLE` query then changed it to a `CREATE VIEW` query but the code was not updated properly in the server.

Comment: What proof that it's a table that's created?

Comment: @e4c5 The query results are listed under ´INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables´ not under ´INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views´. When I run the query directly in the DB, the results are listed in ´INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views´.

Comment: Thanks proof enough!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    CREATE VIEW my_view AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      a.*
    FROM layer_1 a
     JOIN layer_2 b
     ON st_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 10) 
    );
```

Using geometry, you'ld better use an INNER JOIN rather than a WHERE.

Comment: isn't this equivalent to the original query since the original query is an implicit join?

Comment: Thanks! I tired this but the same problem persists.